# /opt/cmake/bin/cmake no file in the directory

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi4, raspbian-buster

I am installing Qt6 using this guide on my fresh raspberry pi 4 running the latest official 32bit OS

https://www.tal.org/tutorials/building-qt-62-raspberry-pi

and i am stuck in the ***Configure the Qt 6.2 build*** portion where it asks me to execute this line

```
/opt/cmake/bin/cmake -G Ninja \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/Qt/6.2.3-armv7l \
-DQT_FEATURE_opengles2=ON \
-DQT_FEATURE_opengles3=ON \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=tc.cmake \
-DQT_AVOID_CMAKE_ARCHIVING_API=ON ../qtbase-everywhere-src-6.2.3
```

but i am getting an error

```
bash: /opt/cmake/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
```

I followed every step behore hand and there were no problems, everthing went smoothly exempt this part. Can anybody help me with this problem ?

Comment: If you have installed Cmake through apt, the default path shold be /usr/bin/cmake.
Try to see if is there. If yes, you might want to replace /opt/cmake/bin/cmake with /usr/bin/cmake. 
Another way to find if you have cmake installed somewhere else would be to run the command:  whereis cmake.

Comment: @AlexisNicole Oh ! yes that worked ! Thank you post it as an answer ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed Cmake through apt, the default path should be

```
/usr/bin/cmake
```

Try to see if is there. If yes, you might want to replace

```
/opt/cmake/bin/cmake
```

with

```
/usr/bin/cmake
```

Another way to find if you have cmake installed somewhere else would be to run the command:

```
whereis cmake
```